# display text radio buttons in columns from reading json file and on select should display value in below div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, vuejs2

A table is to be created from taking values from json file where data should be displayed as radio buttons in columns(one value to be selected from each column). The selected values from each column  should be displayed below the table. Could anyone please help me with this?

My Json is
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" , "manager":"paul", "domain":"digital"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "manager":"Abraham","domain":"mechanics"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "manager":"Jonathan","domain":"physics"}
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"carter", "manager":"Bravo","domain":"chemistry"}
    {"firstName":"Watson", "lastName":"Daniel", "manager":"Pollock","domain":"biology"}
    {"firstName":"James", "lastName":"Smith", "manager":"Tait","domain":"analogy"}
    {"firstName":"Angel", "lastName":"Queen", "manager":"Mcgrath","domain":"mathematics"}
    {"firstName":"Sana", "lastName":"Elizebeth", "manager":"Waugh", "domain":"english"}
]

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: I have added my json data,could you please suggest

Comment: Gimme 2 more hours. I'll get back 2 you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you have to apply the returned value from inside the Observable. What you try is this in the end:

```
const employeesJSON = Observable<any>;
```

And then Angular tries to access the contained objects, which is not possible as an `Observable<any>` is not the same as an array of plain objects.

Try this solution instead:

```
protected employees: Array<Object>;  

ngOnInit() { 
    this.http.get("api.myjson.com/bins/tshu8").pipe(map(res => {

        if (res) {
            this.employees = res.json();
        }

    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution. Please note that this is only a suggestion:

We put 2 tables in the UI.

The first table is for input-purposes. Note the ngFor-loop in the `tr` of the table-body. Here you loop through your list of objects and with every new object a new `tr` gets created. Each `tr` contains 4 `td`'s which contain `input`-elements of type "radio" and a `span`-element showing the content of the field. Controlled by the "name"-attribute each COLUMN builds a single unit. This means that a click on a radio button has only an effect on the state of every other radio button in the same column, not row! And each `input`-element's value gets set in order to provide it when the element is clicked.

The `ngModel`-attribute is the most important part of the story. Whenever you click a radio-button ngModel pushes the value of the clicked element into the connected variable. The second table then gets directly updated whenever `ngModel` updates one of the 4 variables (Interpolation). That's why a click on one radio button then prompts its value in the corresponding field of the "Output Table".

Hope this helps.

In your HTML-File:

```
  <h1>Input Table</h1>

  <div class="row" id="inputTableSector">
    <table id="inputTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>first name</td>
          <td>last name</td>
          <td>manager</td>
          <td>domain</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees;">
          <td><input type="radio" name="firstName" [value]="employee.firstName" [(ngModel)]="currentFirstName"><span>{{employee?.firstName}}</span></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="lastName" [value]="employee.lastName" [(ngModel)]="currentLastName"><span>{{employee?.lastName}}</span></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="manager" [value]="employee.manager" [(ngModel)]="currentManager"><span>{{employee?.manager}}</span></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="domain" [value]="employee.domain" [(ngModel)]="currentDomain"><span>{{employee?.domain}}</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <h1>Output Table</h1>

  <div class="row" id="outputTableSector">
    <table id="outputTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>first name</td>
          <td>last name</td>
          <td>manager</td>
          <td>domain</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{currentFirstName}}</td>
          <td>{{currentLastName}}</td>
          <td>{{currentManager}}</td>
          <td>{{currentDomain}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

In your TypeScript-File:

```
protected employees: Array<Object>;
protected currentLastName: string;
protected currentFirstName: string;
protected currentManager: string;
protected currentDomain: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const employeesJSON = '[' +
    '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","manager":"paul","domain":"digital"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith","manager":"Abraham","domain":"mechanics"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones","manager":"Jonathan","domain":"physics"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"carter","manager":"Bravo","domain":"chemistry"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Watson","lastName":"Daniel","manager":"Pollock","domain":"biology"},' +
    '{"firstName":"James","lastName":"Smith","manager":"Tait","domain":"analogy"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Angel","lastName":"Queen","manager":"Mcgrath","domain":"mathematics"},' +
    '{"firstName":"Sana","lastName":"Elizebeth","manager":"Waugh","domain":"english"}' +
    ']';
  this.employees = JSON.parse(employeesJSON);
}
```

Comment: Here you go. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem. Thx in advance.

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks a lot for the help. I tried getting JSON response from http but it is throwing and error Argument of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
My code is 
ngOnInit() {
    const employeesJSON = this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/tshu8").pipe(map(res => res.json()));
    this.employees = JSON.parse(employeesJSON);
  }
 Could you please help me solve the error

Comment: Please, find my answer to this below.